# How to use Glide with urls?

Tags: android, android-glide, imgur

How can I use *Glide* with urls? I mean, for example an imgur link is accepted to use in *Glide*? Or what sites does the *Glide* accepted to use our linsks?

Comment: Just point (write the url) to the destination of your image. Someone [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1626) asked the same question.

Comment: Did you not see the documentation where it says `url`? https://bumptech.github.io/glide/ The site doesn't matter. The resource being loaded needs to be an image, though

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
Glide.with(context).load(yourImgUrl)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(yourImageView);
```